# How do I install the *latest* version of Emacs?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, emacs

I've downloaded the `.tar.xz` file from the GNU Emacs page, and extracted it, but now I have a huge directory full of files, and I have no idea what to do with them. The `README` is unhelpful, too.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) in [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL) 1. That means I only have a CLI to work with, unless I use an external X server.

I *don't* want any of the `apt` packages for Emacs. I know how to install them, and I want the latest version (GNU Emacs 26.3).

Comment: To start, 1) which Linux version have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.), & 2) which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. 3) Did you want emacs w/ the GTK+,GUI https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/emacs25, the Lucid GUI https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/emacs25-lucid, or no GUI https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/emacs25-nox ? Please click [edit] and add that vital info to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you.

Comment: You want instructions on building `emacs`. The `emacs` source has tons of documentarian, explore. Read `[A-Z]*` to start.

Answer (score 8):

To install WSL 2, you will need the following requirements:

- Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 18917 or higher.
- WSL 2 will be generally available in Windows 10, version 2004 and later.

The latest stable version of Emacs 26.3 is a native Ubuntu package and can be installed in WSL 2 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo snap install emacs --classic
```

The beta version (27 at the time of the answer) can be installed with:

```
sudo snap install emacs --channel=beta --classic
```

The latest development version of Emacs 28.0 can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo snap install emacs --channel=edge --classic
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't use snap in WSL

Comment: The current snap is ( https://github.com/alexmurray/emacs-snap ) . I end up installing from ( `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs` ), which leads me to face with socket problems on `emacs --daemon`.

Comment: What should I do to install emacs v28.1? @karel

Comment: @alper The latest release of Emacs at [GitHub](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs) is currently version 28.0.50. The same version 28.0.50 of Emacs is also a snap package, To install it run `sudo snap install emacs --channel=edge --classic`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [flatpack](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/03/gnu-emacs-27-2-released/) to install 27.2 version

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.gnu.emacs
```